# In XCode 6 how do I change the size of the controller windows to reflect an iPhone 4 or 5 in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

Right now they are in the size of an iPad:

[image]

Can't figure out how to change this.

Help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Xcode 6 and iOS8, Interface Builder comes - by default - with "Size classes" enabled. So what you have in your picture is not an iPad sized `UIViewController` but a `UIViewController` with width: Any and height: Any (see the text "w: Any, h: Any" at the bottom of your picture).

With `w: Any, h: Any`, all the auto layout constraints that you will set in your `UIViewController` will apply for any kind of device (may it be iPad Mini in landscape mode or iPhone 4s in portrait mode). No need for two different storyboards (one for iPad, one for iPhone) anymore in your projects!

Otherwise, if you want / don't want to apply some auto layout constraints to a device / orientation, just click on `w: Any, h: Any`. You will then be able to select a new size class canvas.

If you don't want to deal with Size Classes, you can disable it in the File Inspector of Interface Builder. Xcode will then ask you which type of device size you want to keep.

You can learn more about Size Classes with the [iOS Developper Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) or with the [WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) session 401 "What's new in Xcode 6" video (starts at 27'50").

Comment: I know this will make things much easier I'm going to take the plunge and get used to this. Still trying to totally wrap my head around it. Just wondering how a design would design for a specific device? How would I do all my skinning? I'm still slightly baffled.

Comment: This helped me understand more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM. The apple doc link you provided done it for me. This will be very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Viewcontroller exactly like Xcode 5 then you have to disable size Classes.
or also refer to this link for diffrent size classes
http://carpeaqua.com/2014/06/14/thinking-in-terms-of-ios-8-size-classes/

Comment: After reading that I no longer want to do what I originally intended. This is my first project using Swift and XCode 6. It's going to be a really interesting with all these changes.